# After create New Web Aplications and SiteColection Can't logon to created new Site Colection

Tags: login

I Created a new Web Application and a Site Collection. When I tried to browse to the new Site Collection I couldn't login.

It shows me the login dialog but, when I tried to login it kept showing the dialog again and again and again.

I tried to login from the server and it worked.

But how logon from different location?

Comment: did you properly configured the Object cache on newly created web application? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I think I am. I put my Domain Name.

Comment: what you mean by the domain name....their are two accounts which you need to set as Super Reader as well as SuperUser in Central Admin as well as in Powershell.

Comment: run the below powershell $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "<WebApplication>"   $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]   $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]  and now you will get two accounts, make sure both are added into the Web application's policy for web app

Comment: We menaged afer add a domain name.

Comment: which domain name you are talking about here?